# How to add element obtain from jquery and custom element/tag together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Suppose I got an element from jquery selector and stored in a variable and now I want to add some custom element to that variable before doing some DOM operation on that variable.

For example if I do this:

```
var placeHolder = $('.class-name').children().eq(0).clone();
```

I get an array like this if the children is an input tag:

```
[input#link, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
```

I think above represent selected input tag and now I want to append another tag like:

```
placeHolder = placeHolder + '<span class="delete-btn">X</span>';
```

And now I would like to add this `placeHolder` back to the DOM. But when I do this like `$('.some-class').append(placeHolder);` its throwing error in console.

Here is the error:

```
jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized 
expression: [object Object]<span class="delete-btn">X</span>
```

The weird thing is it's adding `placeHolder` to the DOM but in `[object Object]` format. So How to add those elements got from jquery selector and some custom tag(like 3rd highlighted line) and then add back to DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the span to the placeholder, you convert it to a string. Do not try to concatenate the html, just append your objects like

```
$('.some-class')
  .append(placeHolder)
  .append('<span class="delete-btn">X</span>');
```

Comment: Thank you. it's working. However, what if remove `$` sign from second `append`? Will that make any difference? My code is working in both conditions with or without $ in the second append. Enlighten me little.

Comment: You're right, jQuery will create the dom node from string automatically. Changed that in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating placeholder (a jQuery object) and a string (your span) and passing them to jQuery which is then treating the whole thing as a string.

Use .get(0) and this should fix your issue:

`var placeHolder = $('.class-name').children().eq(0).clone().get(0);`